# How to access emails in All Documents folder in Exchange 2013 via PowerShell/EWS?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

After migrating a mail-in database from Notes to Exchange, the mails have not been placed in the correct Folders.
The Folders are existing but empty, the mails only appear via the "All Documents" Folder.
Now I want to compare the structure to a correctly migrated db copy and restore the folder Contents from that...
For this, I Need to Access the "All Documents" Folder in the Mailbox - how to do that, since it is not contained in the "Wellknown Folder names" enum?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Al lDocuments folder in Exchange (AFAIK that a notes thing) so this was either a Folder that the migration application you used has created or you have used something like http://blog.directionstraining.com/microsoft-outlook/creating-documents-view-outlook to create a search Folder to mimic that behaviour. So depending on the answer the method you would use would be different a really basic Get-Folder from Path (where the path  would be based on the location from root eg if All Documents was a root folder then use '\All Documents' or if All Documents was a folder that was a subfolder of the Inbox you would use '\Inbox\All Documents' etc

```
####################### 
<# 
.SYNOPSIS 
 Enumerates Items in a Mailbox folder in a Mailbox using the  Exchange Web Services API 

.DESCRIPTION 
  Enumerates Items in a Mailbox folder in a Mailbox using the  Exchange Web Services API 

 Requires the EWS Managed API from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42951
.EXAMPLE
 PS C:\>Get-FolderItems -MailboxName user.name@domain.com  -FolderPath '\Reporttest'

#> 
function Get-FolderItems
{ 
    [CmdletBinding()] 
    param( 
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$MailboxName,
        [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)] [PSCredential]$Credentials,
        [Parameter(Position=2, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$FolderPath
    )  
    Begin
         {
        ## Load Managed API dll  
        ###CHECK FOR EWS MANAGED API, IF PRESENT IMPORT THE HIGHEST VERSION EWS DLL, ELSE EXIT
        $EWSDLL = (($(Get-ItemProperty -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Path Registry::$(Get-ChildItem -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Path 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services'|Sort-Object Name -Descending| Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty Name)).'Install Directory') + "Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll")
        if (Test-Path $EWSDLL)
            {
            Import-Module $EWSDLL
            }
        else
            {
            "$(get-date -format yyyyMMddHHmmss):"
            "This script requires the EWS Managed API 1.2 or later."
            "Please download and install the current version of the EWS Managed API from"
            "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=255472"
            ""
            "Exiting Script."
            exit
            } 

        ## Set Exchange Version  
        $ExchangeVersion = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2010_SP2  

        ## Create Exchange Service Object  
        $service = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService($ExchangeVersion)  

        ## Set Credentials to use two options are availible Option1 to use explict credentials or Option 2 use the Default (logged On) credentials  

        #Credentials Option 1 using UPN for the windows Account  
        #$psCred = Get-Credential  
        $creds = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Credentials.UserName.ToString(),$Credentials.GetNetworkCredential().password.ToString())  
        $service.Credentials = $creds      
        #Credentials Option 2  
        #service.UseDefaultCredentials = $true  
         #$service.TraceEnabled = $true
        ## Choose to ignore any SSL Warning issues caused by Self Signed Certificates  

        ## Code From http://poshcode.org/624
        ## Create a compilation environment
        $Provider=New-Object Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider
        $Compiler=$Provider.CreateCompiler()
        $Params=New-Object System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters
        $Params.GenerateExecutable=$False
        $Params.GenerateInMemory=$True
        $Params.IncludeDebugInformation=$False
        $Params.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.DLL") | Out-Null

$TASource=@'
  namespace Local.ToolkitExtensions.Net.CertificatePolicy{
    public class TrustAll : System.Net.ICertificatePolicy {
      public TrustAll() { 
      }
      public bool CheckValidationResult(System.Net.ServicePoint sp,
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate cert, 
        System.Net.WebRequest req, int problem) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
'@ 
        $TAResults=$Provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource($Params,$TASource)
        $TAAssembly=$TAResults.CompiledAssembly

        ## We now create an instance of the TrustAll and attach it to the ServicePointManager
        $TrustAll=$TAAssembly.CreateInstance("Local.ToolkitExtensions.Net.CertificatePolicy.TrustAll")
        [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy=$TrustAll

        ## end code from http://poshcode.org/624

        ## Set the URL of the CAS (Client Access Server) to use two options are availbe to use Autodiscover to find the CAS URL or Hardcode the CAS to use  

        #CAS URL Option 1 Autodiscover  
        $service.AutodiscoverUrl($MailboxName,{$true})  
        "Using CAS Server : " + $Service.url   

        #CAS URL Option 2 Hardcoded  

        #$uri=[system.URI] "https://casservername/ews/exchange.asmx"  
        #$service.Url = $uri    

        ## Optional section for Exchange Impersonation  

        #$service.ImpersonatedUserId = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ImpersonatedUserId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ConnectingIdType]::SmtpAddress, $MailboxName) 

        $fldId = FolderIdFromPath -FolderPath $FolderPath  -SmtpAddress $MailboxName
        $SubFolderId =  new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId($fldId)


        #Define ItemView to retrive just 1000 Items    
        $ivItemView =  New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView(1000) 
        $PR_RETENTION_DATE = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x301C,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MapiPropertyType]::SystemTime); 
        $ItemPropset= new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BasePropertySet]::FirstClassProperties)
        $ItemPropset.Add($PR_RETENTION_DATE);
        $ivItemView.PropertySet = $ItemPropset
        $rptCollection = @{}
        $fiItems = $null    
        do{    
            $fiItems = $service.FindItems($SubFolderId,$ivItemView)    
            #[Void]$service.LoadPropertiesForItems($fiItems,$psPropset)  
            foreach($Item in $fiItems.Items){      
                #Process Item
                Write-Host $Item.Subject
            }    
            $ivItemView.Offset += $fiItems.Items.Count    
        }while($fiItems.MoreAvailable -eq $true)    
        }
}
function FolderIdFromPath{
    param (
            $FolderPath = "$( throw 'Folder Path is a mandatory Parameter' )",
            $SmtpAddress = "$( throw 'Folder Path is a mandatory Parameter' )"
          )
    process{
        ## Find and Bind to Folder based on Path  
        #Define the path to search should be seperated with \  
        #Bind to the MSGFolder Root  
        $folderid = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::MsgFolderRoot,$SmtpAddress)   
        $tfTargetFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service,$folderid)  
        #Split the Search path into an array  
        $fldArray = $FolderPath.Split("\") 
         #Loop through the Split Array and do a Search for each level of folder 
        for ($lint = 1; $lint -lt $fldArray.Length; $lint++) { 
            #Perform search based on the displayname of each folder level 
            $fvFolderView = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderView(1) 
            $SfSearchFilter = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderSchema]::DisplayName,$fldArray[$lint]) 
            $findFolderResults = $service.FindFolders($tfTargetFolder.Id,$SfSearchFilter,$fvFolderView) 
            if ($findFolderResults.TotalCount -gt 0){ 
                foreach($folder in $findFolderResults.Folders){ 
                    $tfTargetFolder = $folder                
                } 
            } 
            else{ 
                "Error Folder Not Found"  
                $tfTargetFolder = $null  
                break  
            }     
        }  
        if($tfTargetFolder -ne $null){
            return $tfTargetFolder.Id.UniqueId.ToString()
        }
        else{
            throw "Folder not found"
        }
    }
}
```

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Hi Glen, you're right - the Folder has been created by the Dell Migrator... Even so, this is the perfect answer for me. Many thanks for your help :)